# Problem with list-style-type: none; in FireFox

Tags: css

For example, in that html code I add `list-style-type: none;` in external test.css. When FireFox loads that page, the `dots (list-style-type without none)` could be seen for about a second. Only inline css works `<ul id="categories" style="list-style-image: none; list-style-type: none;">`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <ul id="categories">
            <li><a>Test1</a></li>
            <li><a>Test2</a></li>
            <li><a>Test3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

[ScreenShot](http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/4/e/upload/4c82c45d.png)

Comment: What you are seeing is a [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) -- Flash Of Unstyled Content -- if that helps you track anything down.

Comment: Thank you for that great link!!! Adding script tag to the document head solved that problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tried it on both Windows and Mac in Firefox, and both worked fine for me. Apparently, this Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC) doesn't happen on everyone's browser.

If you insist fixing this, you might think about using some workarounds, such as placing the `<link>` in `body`, using `@import` to import your css, or [google it](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=lt3&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&q=Flash%20of%20Unstyled%20Content%20fix&aq=f&aqi=g3g-sv1g-v6&aql=&oq=)...

Comment: Thank you for answer. Solution #3 from here http://www.techrepublic.com/article/prevent-the-flash-of-unstyled-content/5140996   solved the problem.

Comment: This is the same thing that i am trying to say the OP for the last 40 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

use this css to remove the dots:

```
ul
{
    list-style:none;
}
```

Here is the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v23UU/)

Comment: No :) Question is not about that. It works in jsfiddle, I've tested. But it does not work if I load that page in FireFox.

Comment: FireFox shows dots for about a second and then becomes normal.

Comment: I tested the same fiddle on IE, Chrome, Safari, Mozilla Firefox 3.0 and 4.0 Developer Preview. All give the same result.

Comment: Have you tested it in jsfiddle?

Comment: I tested it as a single html file on my pc, and also tested it as a fiddle on all these browsers. all are same. no kind of dot flicks in the begining.

Comment: I understood your problem. I may be a kind of bug in your  browser. But i dont face any errors in this.

Comment: You do not see that probably because you're loading page from local machine, not from internet. Matt Gibson gave explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content   Thank you for answer.

Comment: I said na, i loaded the page from Internet. I made the JSFIDDLE myself on Mozilla Firefox. Rite now i am using it too.... so how can you say that i am using offline access to the code? I guess my browser works fine.